# hover / setInterval : undefined time lapse

Tags: jquery, hover, setinterval

i try to use a 'hover' function and a setInterval for the same div : if we hover the div, the setInterval starts.
But i have a problem : it seems that for 2 different divs, when i hover the second div, it first 'waits' 1000 ms before starting the 'setInterval' of the second div. So when i hover the second div, both of them stay with their current image, and after a moment the setInterval of the second div starts. (i would like it to be quick, not wait for those ms).

Do you know how i could do that?
here's my code :

```
var intval;    
    img.bind('mouseenter', function(){   
        var that = $(this);  
    intval = setInterval(function(){  
        next(that);  
    },1000);  
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){  
    var that = $(this);  
    clearInterval(intval);  
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that really all the code?  Are you really trying to share a single "intval" timer reference for two separate timers?

Comment: Also, the "waiting" is probably because "setInterval()" won't run your function until the first timer period has elapsed.

Comment: hi, yeah i use 'intval' for the clearInterval to 'stop' the one that is currently working. I think also the time lapse comes from the '1000' in the setInterval, but i haven't found yet the perfect solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `next()` in the `mouseenter` event it should work.

```
var intval;    

img.bind('mouseenter', function(){   
    var that = $(this);  
    next(that);
    intval = setInterval(function(){  
        next(that);  
    }, 1000);  
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){  
    var that = $(this);  
    clearInterval(intval);  
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks, well it kind of works, but sometimes the time lapse is different, and it works better after hovering the divs several times... is there any other solution?

Comment: Also, there is a difference of time lapse when the pictures switch to one another, quite weird, i use the function 'next' like that (i hope it will be shown correctly in this comment ;) ) here it is :

Comment: `code`function next(elem){      
      var img_li = elem.find('li');  
      count++;  
    if (count>2) count=0;  
  
    img_li.eq(count).fadeIn(function(){  
        img_li.eq(current).css({'display':'none'});  
        current = count;  
    });  
}  `code` Do you have any idea?